# Access VBA random value from combobox

Tags: ms-access, random, combobox, vba

I have a combobox of client codes that links to table - ClientT.

When I click a button randomcmd I would like a random client code to appear in the combobox.

My thought was use VBA code to find the maximum number of clients in ClientT, then Rnd function to pick a number between max and 0, then convert that number to a value from the list.

I just can't find any similar code to use. all I have so far is a number that generates randomly.

```
Private Sub Randomcmd_Click()
    ClientCodecmb = Int(999 * Rnd) + 1
End Sub
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If the customer id is the first column of the combobox and this is the bound column, this will do:

```
Private Sub Randomcmd_Click()

    Dim MaxCustomerId = 1000 ' Adjust as needed.

    Me!ClientCodecmb.Value = Int((MaxCustomerID + 1) * Rnd

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ClientCodecmb = DLookup("[ClientCode]", "ClientT", "Int((DMax('[Autonumber]', 'ClientT')) * Rnd) + 1 = [Autonumber]")
```

I added an autonumber field on the table and the above code works.
looks up the client code, where the max autonumber is random and = to autonumber on the table.

Comment: Well, sort of. Whenever you close and relaunce the application, the combobox will select the same sequence of customers.